# Adding an image near the footer on WooCommerce completed orders email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I'm trying this code to insert images just near the footer in WooCommerce completed orders email notification, but unfortunately it doesn't work!

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
    <?php
    echo ("Hello");
    ?>
    <div>
        <img src="myPic.jpg" alt="myPic" />
    </div>
```

Any Clue please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better use a custom hooked function in **`woocommerce_email_customer_details`** action hook for example, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'custom_image_near_email_footer' , 50, 4);
function custom_image_near_email_footer( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {    
    // For customer order notification with "completed" status
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' == $email->id ) 
        echo '<div style="text-align:center;">
            <img src="'.home_url( "wp-content/uploads/2017/05/myPic.jpg" ).'" alt="myPic"/>
        </div>';
}
```

> You could also use **`woocommerce_email_footer`** action hook instead which have only one argument (**`$email`** argument).

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works on WooCommerce version 2.6.x and 3.0+

Comment: i've just tried your code and again it works like a charm. Great thanks SIR