# Adding an image with hyperlink in a php woocommerce email

Tags: php, woocommerce, html-email

Hi I am trying the below code form [Adding an image near the footer on WooCommerce completed orders email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067555/adding-an-image-near-the-footer-on-woocommerce-completed-orders-email-notificati)

However, cannot figure out how I can add a link to the image to create  hyperlink like a src in html. Any ideas please?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'custom_image_near_email_footer' , 50, 4);
function custom_image_near_email_footer( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // For customer order notification with "completed" status
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' == $email->id )
        echo '<div style="text-align:center;">
            <img src="'.home_url( "image.png" ).'" alt="image"/>
        </div>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolved this by adding "a href="google.com"

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'custom_image_near_email_footer' , 50, 4);
function custom_image_near_email_footer( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // For customer order notification with "completed" status
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' == $email->id )
        echo '<div style="text-align:center;">
            <a href="google.com"><img src="'.home_url( "image.png" ).'" alt="image"/>
        </div>';
}
```

Comment: make sure you include `https://`. As it stands, it *might* work in some email clients, but not all of them